# How do I append to an external file with the top 5 scores and respective user

Tags: python

I've come across many issues with this code but I'm again stumped on how to do this.

I would like to add the score and username into an external file which stays in that file and can later be accessed in another game as a top 5 scores and who got them. So far I've gotten this:

```
score = '11'
gametag = 'Griminal'
with open("scores.txt", "a+") as out_file:
    print(out_file)
    out_string = ""
    out_string += str(score) + " points from: " + str(gametag)
    out_string += "\n"
    print(out_string)
    out_file.append(out_string)
    print(out_file)
```

However as I've noticed the file doesn't open as a list but instead as:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='scores.txt' mode='a+' encoding='cp1252'>
```

which gets printed into the shell when i run the print(out_file)

And so I can't append the new scores into the list and save it into the file. Does anyone have a solution to these issues?

To sort it I have the code:

```
f = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
top5 = f[:5]
print(top5)
```

Which works as far as I'm aware.

The error code i receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gemma/OneDrive/Desktop/Gcse coursework.py", line 60, in 
<module>
    out_file.append(out_string)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Where exactly does it print out the `<_io.TextIOWrapper name=....` block? And what 
specifically happens when you run the example above?

Comment: <_io.TextIOWrapper name=.... prints out into the shell when it runs the print(out_file) and the code its self exports:

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='scores.txt' mode='a+' encoding='cp1252'>
11 points from: Griminal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gemma/OneDrive/Desktop/Gcse coursework.py", line 60, in <module>
    out_file.append(out_string)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Sorry for not including this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Appending to the file**

`out_file` is not a list. You have to use the `write()` method to write on a file. Also `print(out_file)` prints the object representation, not the content of the file.

Just substitute `out_file.append()` with `out_file.write()`:

```
score = '11'
gametag = 'Griminal'
with open("scores.txt", "a") as out_file:
    out_string = str(score) + " points from: " + str(gametag) + "\n"
    print(out_string)
    out_file.write(out_string)
```

**Sorting the file**

As far as I know, there is no easy way to sort the file in place. Maybe other people can suggest you a better way, but I would read the whole file in a list (each row of the file as an element of the list), sort it and then save it again in the file. This, of course, if you need the file itself being sorted. If your sorting is just for printing purpose (i.e. you don't care if the file itself is sorted) then just save the new score in the file, then read it and have the script sort the output before printing.

This is how you can read and print the sorting result:

```
with open("scores.txt", "r") as scores:
    lines = scores.readlines() #reads all the lines

sortedlines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), reverse=True) #be sure of the index on which to sort!
for i in sortedlines[:5]: #the first 5 only
    print(i)
```

`x.split()` splits each row into a list of words, using whitespaces as separator. Here I use index 0 because following the previous input `out_string = str(score) + " points from: " + str(gametag) + "\n"` the score is in the first element of the list.

If you need to save the file again you can overwrite it writing the `sortedlines` in it.

```
with open("scores.txt", "w") as out_file: #mode "w" deletes any previous content
    for i in sortedlines:
        out_file.write(i)
```

Comment: I've implemented what you've said and it works great now thank you very much, I'm sorry for the basic mistakes i'm very new to coding. Im sorry for taking you time but do you know how i would re write:    f = sorted(out_file, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) so that it will sort my new file, 3 points from: Griminal is the string in the file

Comment: Hei, we are here to learn. I will edit the answer for the sorting part

Comment: Thank you so much, I've added that and it works perfectly now and i even understand whats going on. You've been an amazing help

Answer (score 0):

After opening the file you need to read its contents and to append you need to write. Inside the `with` statement do the following to read:

```
file_content = out_file.read()
```

and the following to append:

```
out_file.write("Your output")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said out_file is not a list but an object (file pointer) that has methods to access your file content like

```
out_file.read()
```

if you want read in the contents of the file as a list you can do

```
top_scores = out_file.read().split('\n')
```

and continue appending to it with `out_file.write()`