# How to create a simple ordered leaderboard for top 5 players in a text file for a one player game

Tags: python

I'm making a 1 player quiz and need to implement a high score system that records the score of the top 5 highscorers and the player names appropriate to the scorer. This should be written to a text file (.txt) and overwritten if the score is higher (sorted from 1. highest score to 5. lowest score). If someone could share some code I could use for my highscore system that would be really helpful.

The players that get through n rounds should be ordered from highest n score to lowest n score. It should have the top 5 n scores in a txt file, ordered.

I've looked at loads of forums for hours and was unable to implement codes I found into my code. Side note: I don't know how to do this at all

```
counter = 0
print("The songs' initials are " ,initialsofsong, " and the name of the artist is " ,randomartist)
print (randomsong)
songnameguess = input("Guess the name of the song!")
counter = counter + 1
while counter < 3 and songnameguess != randomsong :
        songnameguess = input("Nope! Try again!")
        counter = counter + 1
if songnameguess == randomsong:
    print ("Well done!")
    if counter == 2:
        score = score + 1
    elif counter == 1:
        score = score + 3

elif counter >=3 and songnameguess != randomsong:
    print ("Sorry, you've had two chances. Come back soon!")
    print ("Game over.")
    print (score)
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Do you know how to write to / read from a file? Do you know how to sort lists?

Comment: I know how to read/write from a file. I don't know how to sort a list successfully in a file.

Comment: well, you don't sort "in a file". You read the file, add the scores to a list, append the current score, sort this list in descending order and take the first 5 elements, e.g. using `high_scores = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:5]`, and write that back to the file.

Comment: what information is inside your text file? How does it look like? Can you post an example file?

Comment: I remember a similar question. Have a look at my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223977/10426037)

Answer (score 2):

You could store the score in many formats, I'll go for [json](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) since it is readable and builtin:

```
score_file = r"/pat/to/score/file.json"

# at the beginning of your script: load the current scores
try:
    with open(score_file, 'r') as f:
        scores = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    scores = {}

# (...)

# during your script: update the scores with the player's new
scores[player_name] = new_score

# (...)

# at the end of your script: store the new scores
with open(score_file, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(scores, f)
```

To print your scores sorted:

```
scores_sorted = sorted([(p, s) for p, s in scores.items()], reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
for player, score in scores_sorted:
    print(player, score)
```

Comment: How would you do this in a txt file?

Comment: You mean with a `.txt` file? Why would you do that? JSON is a type of text file, it is just formatted to be read by a programming language, look there: [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation)

Comment: It's listed in the requirements of the project to use a .txt file

Comment: Ok, so you'll need to adapt this code a little. Replace `json.load()` and `json.dump()` by `f.read()` and `f.write(scores)` - Use a list to store the top scores instead of a dict - Use the `join()` and the `split()` to convert the list into string and string into list.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a class like this (if multiple users have the same score then they are all on the highscore, see example):

```
import json

class Highscore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.highscores = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        """Loads highscores from a file called 'highscores.txt'"""
        try:
            with open('highscores.txt', 'r') as handle:
                text = handle.read()
                if text:
                    self.highscores = json.loads(text)
                    return
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        self.highscores = {}

    def update(self, name, score):
        """Update current highscore for user and keep only top 5 users"""
        self.highscores[name] = max(score, self.highscores.get(name, 0))
        self.highscores = {n: s for n, s in self.highscores.items()
                           if s in sorted(self.highscores.values(), reverse=True)[:5]}
    def save(self):
        """Saves highscores to a file called 'highscores.txt'"""
        with open('highscores.txt', 'w') as handle:
            json.dump(self.highscores, handle)

    def clear(self):
        """Remves highscores (in memory, save is needed to clear record)"""
        self.highscores = {}

    def __str__(self):
        """Return highscores as a string"""
        return '\n'.join(
            f'{name}: {score}'
            for name, score in
            sorted(self.highscores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        ) or 'No highscores!'
```

Example:

```
import random

highscores = Highscore()  # Loads the current highscores
highscores.clear()  # Removes them
highscores.save()  # Saves to file
highscores.load()  # Loads from file again (to make sure save worked)
print(highscores)  # prints: "No highscores!"

# Generate random scores:
for i in range(10):
    highscores.update(f'name{i}', random.randint(10, 100))

print(highscores)
# prints:
# name9: 94
# name8: 79
# name1: 62
# name6: 57
# name0: 48 Same score as below so both are kept...
# name4: 48 Same score as above so both are kept...
```